# What Ruby and Rails Developers Ought To Know?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What should someone know as an Entry Level, Mid-level, and Senior Developer working with Rails? Across the board: theoretical knowledge, development tools, gems and more. What issues usually are at the interview?

Comment: Add `subjective` tag and make community wiki

Comment: Are you only interested in criteria for rails developers, or are you also interested in developers using plain old ruby objects?

Comment: I am interested in everything connected with Ruby.

Comment: Is that a joke or did `subjective` actually used to be a tag?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

**Senior**

- Analyse and profile an application for performance and memory issues
- Analyses and profile an application for security issues
- Understand database modeling and query analysis
- Tune a production deployment (Passenger, Thin, Apache etc)
- Understand and use Ruby metaprogramming
- Mentoring skills
- Communication skills
- Planning and Estimation

**Mid-level**

- Setup and deploy a Rails App for production
- Understand the Rails stack - callbacks, filters, plugins, engines, gems, rack
- Understand and use Active Record associations
- Understand and use scopes to define model abstractions
- Define tests using Cucumber and rSpec
- Understand and use Object Orientation
- Understand and use Design Patterns (explain what they are, know some basic patterns)

**Entry Level**

- Create and setup a Rails environment
- Use generators to create models, controllers and migrations
- Create and use a migration to manage the database
- Create a unit test using rspec/etc
- Create a model and basic validations
- Handle a GET request using a Controller, Model, and View
- Handle a POST request using a Controller, Model, and View
- Basic HTML, CSS and JavaScript
- Basic GIT - clone, commit, push

Comment: This is a very good list, I would add model validation to the Entry Level or Mid-Level sections.  I've found that writing validations first when creating a resource helps you think critically about your application and its data early in the development process.

Comment: Thats a pretty damn good list for anyone regardless of language. Understand your application stack. Understand the build system. Understand your test tools. Understand profiling tools. Etc. However I would recommend scrapping CSS and going straight for SASS. The power of sass is so great that while its still CSS, its like assembly vs c really.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote down some questions and answers that I have experienced from my interviews and some additional logic questions that you might find useful.

Here it is:
http://anilpunjabi.tumblr.com/post/25948339235/ruby-and-rails-interview-questions-and-answers

Enjoy !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think for the seniority level you should be able to answer most of the following questions:

Here is my [blog link](http://smsohan.blogspot.ca/2010/02/ruby-on-rails-interview-questions_23.html).

Answer (score 0):

How to setup and deploy Rails apps to production environment

Answer (score 0):

Understand ruby blocks and iterators for traversing and manipulating datasets.