# How to prepare an interview for Ruby on Rails developer position?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Background about myself:**

I have about 3 years experience working in Java/J2EE. I am currently pursuing MS in Software Engineering at a reputed university. I have done several classwork projects on Ruby on Rails and can be considered at Intermediate level expertise with ROR.

I have an interview coming up next week for a Ruby on Rails developer position at a startup. I have already prepared all the basics of Ruby on Rails but didn't get a lot input on the questions asked for ROR developers. Can you guys help me with the preparation?  Any materials, suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some responses prepared earlier: [What Ruby and Rails Developers Ought To Know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569501/what-ruby-and-rails-developers-ought-to-know/2569865#2569865)

Some of this is going to depend on the level of the role your are looking at. If I was interviewing someone from the Java world I would be probing to make sure they understood some of the common Ruby idioms, particularly blocks and closures.

Answer (score 5):

Create a github account and made some patch to several project.

Be active in Open source community. It's really a good start